# Unable to install the jade plugin for Pycharm (MacOs)

Tags: plugins, pug, pycharm

I have installed PyCharm 3.4.1 CE for my Mac. I was able to install the jade plugin from  `Preferences > Plugins > Browse repositories`, however, the plugin will fail to start with the following error message, saying the `com.intellij.css` is not installed.

Error message:

```
Plugin Error
       Problems found loading plugins:

       Plugin "Jade" was not loaded: required plugin "com.intellij.css" not installed.
       Disable Jade
       Open plugin manager
```

I can't find where to install the missing plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Plugin depends on com.intellij.css. It is only part of the Ultimate Edition. There is no support for the plugin in the CE.

Comment: Though I already gave up PyCharm long ago, still thank you for your answer. It should state the Jade plugin supports only Ultimate Edition. (I would have paid if I knew this back then)